# Need help in retrieving anchor text using JavaScript without using div id

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to retrieve anchor text from a link. So whenever I click on any link on that form, that particular anchor text should be displayed as an alert.

Comment: Will an anchor of 'that form' have a specific class?

Comment: it doesnt have specific class

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your function!

Answer (score 1):

I would delegate the clicks on the form to any anchor link that has a specific class, we call call the class: `myAnchor`

So your code should look like this:

```
$('#form').on('click', '.myAnchor', function()
{
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

This code will only fire off the alert if the anchor has the class `myAnchor`

UPDATE:
Since your anchor link doesn't have a specific class, just use this:

```
$('#form').on('click', 'a', function()
{
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the alert fire for all of the links within just a specific form, you can do so with jQuery:

```
$('#form > a').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

This will only fire when a link is clicked that is inside the form.